# iPhone 4 - camera flash

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to write a program for iPhone 4 that uses its camera flash.

Is that possible?
If so, which class should I work with?

Thanks in advance,

sagiftw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible...Not sure what exactly you want to do but look at AVFoundation framework specifically AVCaptureDevice [AVCaptureDevice ref](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/flashMode)